# Parsing HTML does not output desired data (tracking info for FedEx)

Tags: python, html-parsing, urllib, fedex

I'm trying to make a script that grabs tracking information from fedex website.

I figured that if I just go to the url 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers='  and paste the tracking number at the end of it, it brings me to the tracking page which has the information i need.

I tried to feed the URL the tracking number and parse the html from the response.

This is what I tried.

```
import urllib

url_prefix= 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers='
tracking_number = '570573906561'
url = url_prefix + tracking_number
sock = urllib.urlopen(url) htmlSource = sock.read()
sock.close()
print htmlSource
```

this code outputs:
http://freetexthost.com/iy1ma2q1fm

I thought i would just be able to search the text from the output and find the delivery status/date but it is not in this output.

If i go to the tracking page in Chrome and inspect element, I see that the delivery date information has an id of destionDateTime,
so if i run this in the Chrome Console:

```
var document.getElementbyID('destinationDateTime')
```

it returns the output I want (delivery date)

How come my python script doesn't print actual tracking data information or that class in the html output?

I tried searching this question and tried parsing several different ways (Mechanize, Beautiful Soup, html2text) but all of these gave me the same output that does not contain any actual data about the shipment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The website, like many others, won't work without JavaScript. It sends a HTTP POST request to a certain URL, which then returns the tracking data as a JSON-encoded object.

You'll need to simulate that with Python:

```
import requests
import json

tracking_number = '570573906561'

data = requests.post('https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track', data={
    'data': json.dumps({
        'TrackPackagesRequest': {
            'appType': 'wtrk',
            'uniqueKey': '',
            'processingParameters': {
                'anonymousTransaction': True,
                'clientId': 'WTRK',
                'returnDetailedErrors': True,
                'returnLocalizedDateTime': False
            },
            'trackingInfoList': [{
                'trackNumberInfo': {
                    'trackingNumber': tracking_number,
                    'trackingQualifier': '',
                    'trackingCarrier': ''
                }
            }]
        }
    }),
    'action': 'trackpackages',
    'locale': 'en_US',
    'format': 'json',
    'version': 99
}).json()
```

And then work with the resulting object:

```
{
    "TrackPackagesResponse": {
        "successful": true,
        "passedLoggedInCheck": false,
        "errorList": [{
            "code": "0",
            "message": "Request was successfully processed.",
            "source": null
        }],
        "packageList": [{
            "trackingNbr": "570573906561",
            "trackingQualifier": "2456536000\u007e570573906561\u007eFX",
            "trackingCarrierCd": "FDXE",
            "trackingCarrierDesc": "FedEx Express",
            "displayTrackingNbr": "570573906561",
            "shipperCmpnyName": "",
            "shipperName": "",
            "shipperAddr1": "",
            "shipperAddr2": "",
            "shipperCity": "SEOUL",
            "shipperStateCD": "",
            "shipperZip": "",
            "shipperCntryCD": "KR",
            "shipperPhoneNbr": "",
            "shippedBy": "",
            "recipientCmpnyName": "",
            "recipientName": "",
            "recipientAddr1": "",
            "recipientAddr2": "",
            "recipientCity": "CHEK LAP KOK",
            "recipientStateCD": "",
            "recipientZip": "",
            "recipientCntryCD": "HK",
            "recipientPhoneNbr": "",
            "shippedTo": "",
            "keyStatus": "Delivered",
            "keyStatusCD": "DL",
            "lastScanStatus": "",
            "lastScanDateTime": "",
            "receivedByNm": ".CHOP",
            "subStatus": "Signed for by\u003a .CHOP",
            "mainStatus": "",
            "statusBarCD": "DL",
            "shortStatus": "",
            "shortStatusCD": "",
            "statusLocationAddr1": "",
            "statusLocationAddr2": "",
            "statusLocationCity": "CHEK LAP KOK",
            "statusLocationStateCD": "",
            "statusLocationZip": "",
            "statusLocationCntryCD": "HK",
            "statusWithDetails": "Delivered\u003a 9\u002f02\u002f2013 11\u003a58 am Signed for by\u003a.CHOP\u003b CHEK LAP KOK, HK",
            "shipDt": "2013\u002d08\u002d31T15\u003a00\u003a00\u002b09\u003a00",
            "displayShipDt": "8\u002f31\u002f2013",
            "displayShipTm": "3\u003a00 pm",
            "displayShipDateTime": "8\u002f31\u002f2013 3\u003a00 pm",
            "pickupDt": "2013\u002d08\u002d31T15\u003a00\u003a00\u002b09\u003a00",
            "displayPickupDt": "8\u002f31\u002f2013",
            "displayPickupTm": "3\u003a00 pm",
            "displayPickupDateTime": "8\u002f31\u002f2013 3\u003a00 pm",
            "estDeliveryDt": "",
            "estDeliveryTm": "",
            "displayEstDeliveryDt": "",
            "displayEstDeliveryTm": "",
            "displayEstDeliveryDateTime": "",
            "actDeliveryDt": "2013\u002d09\u002d02T11\u003a58\u003a00\u002b08\u003a00",
            "displayActDeliveryDt": "9\u002f02\u002f2013",
            "displayActDeliveryTm": "11\u003a58 am",
            "displayActDeliveryDateTime": "9\u002f02\u002f2013 11\u003a58 am",
            "nickName": "",
            "note": "",
            "matchedAccountList": [""],
            "fxfAdvanceETA": "",
            "fxfAdvanceReason": "",
            "fxfAdvanceStatusCode": "",
            "fxfAdvanceStatusDesc": "",
            "destLink": "",
            "originLink": "",
            "hasBillOfLadingImage": false,
            "hasBillPresentment": false,
            "signatureRequired": 0,
            "totalKgsWgt": "3.5",
            "displayTotalKgsWgt": "3.5 kgs",
            "totalLbsWgt": "7.8",
            "displayTotalLbsWgt": "7.8 lbs",
            "displayTotalWgt": "7.8 lbs \u002f 3.5 kgs",
            "pkgKgsWgt": "3.5",
            "displayPkgKgsWgt": "3.5 kgs",
            "pkgLbsWgt": "7.8",
            "displayPkgLbsWgt": "7.8 lbs",
            "displayPkgWgt": "7.8 lbs \u002f 3.5 kgs",
            "dimensions": "20x14x14 in.",
            "masterTrackingNbr": "",
            "masterQualifier": "",
            "masterCarrierCD": "",
            "originalOutboundTrackingNbr": null,
            "originalOutboundQualifier": "",
            "originalOutboundCarrierCD": "",
            "invoiceNbrList": [""],
            "referenceList": [""],
            "doorTagNbrList": [""],
            "referenceDescList": [""],
            "purchaseOrderNbrList": [""],
            "billofLadingNbrList": [""],
            "shipperRefList": ["PO\u00232612  Proton housing\u005fPlastics"],
            "rmaList": [""],
            "deptNbrList": [""],
            "shipmentIdList": [""],
            "tcnList": [""],
            "partnerCarrierNbrList": [""],
            "hasAssociatedShipments": false,
            "hasAssociatedReturnShipments": false,
            "assocShpGrp": 0,
            "drTgGrp": ["0"],
            "associationInfoList": [{
                "trackingNumberInfo": {
                    "trackingNumber": "",
                    "trackingQualifier": "",
                    "trackingCarrier": "",
                    "processingParameters": null
                },
                "associatedType": ""
            }],
            "returnReason": "",
            "returnRelationship": null,
            "skuItemUpcCdList": [""],
            "receiveQtyList": [""],
            "itemDescList": [""],
            "partNbrList": [""],
            "serviceCD": "INTERNATIONAL\u005fPRIORITY",
            "serviceDesc": "FedEx International Priority",
            "serviceShortDesc": "IP",
            "packageType": "YOUR\u005fPACKAGING",
            "packaging": "Your Packaging",
            "clearanceDetailLink": "",
            "showClearanceDetailLink": false,
            "manufactureCountryCDList": [""],
            "commodityCDList": [""],
            "commodityDescList": [""],
            "cerNbrList": [""],
            "cerComplaintCDList": [""],
            "cerComplaintDescList": [""],
            "cerEventDateList": [""],
            "displayCerEventDateList": [""],
            "totalPieces": "1",
            "specialHandlingServicesList": ["Deliver Weekday", "Weekend Pick\u002dUp"],
            "shipmentType": "",
            "pkgContentDesc1": "",
            "pkgContentDesc2": "",
            "docAWBNbr": "",
            "originalCharges": "",
            "transportationCD": "",
            "transportationDesc": "",
            "dutiesAndTaxesCD": "",
            "dutiesAndTaxesDesc": "",
            "origPieceCount": "",
            "destPieceCount": "",
            "goodsClassificationCD": "",
            "receipientAddrQty": "0",
            "deliveryAttempt": "0",
            "codReturnTrackNbr": "",
            "scanEventList": [{
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "11\u003a58\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "Delivered",
                "statusCD": "DL",
                "scanLocation": "CHEK LAP KOK HK",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": true
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "09\u003a36\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "On FedEx vehicle for delivery",
                "statusCD": "OD",
                "scanLocation": "LANTAU ISLAND HK",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "08\u003a55\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "At local FedEx facility",
                "statusCD": "AR",
                "scanLocation": "LANTAU ISLAND HK",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "07\u003a12\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "International shipment release \u002d Import",
                "statusCD": "CC",
                "scanLocation": "LANTAU ISLAND HK",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "04\u003a40\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "Shipment exception",
                "statusCD": "SE",
                "scanLocation": "GUANGZHOU CN",
                "scanDetails": "Delay beyond our control",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "03\u003a45\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "Departed FedEx location",
                "statusCD": "DP",
                "scanLocation": "GUANGZHOU CN",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d02",
                "time": "01\u003a17\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "Arrived at FedEx location",
                "statusCD": "AR",
                "scanLocation": "GUANGZHOU CN",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d01",
                "time": "23\u003a10\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b08\u003a00",
                "status": "In transit",
                "statusCD": "IT",
                "scanLocation": "SHANGHAI CN",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d09\u002d01",
                "time": "17\u003a13\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b09\u003a00",
                "status": "In transit",
                "statusCD": "IT",
                "scanLocation": "INCHEON KR",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d08\u002d31",
                "time": "19\u003a44\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b09\u003a00",
                "status": "In transit",
                "statusCD": "IT",
                "scanLocation": "INCHEON KR",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d08\u002d31",
                "time": "16\u003a27\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b09\u003a00",
                "status": "Left FedEx origin facility",
                "statusCD": "DP",
                "scanLocation": "SEOUL KR",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d08\u002d31",
                "time": "15\u003a00\u003a00",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002b09\u003a00",
                "status": "Picked up",
                "statusCD": "PU",
                "scanLocation": "SEOUL KR",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }, {
                "date": "2013\u002d08\u002d30",
                "time": "23\u003a58\u003a11",
                "gmtOffset": "\u002d05\u003a00",
                "status": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
                "statusCD": "OC",
                "scanLocation": "",
                "scanDetails": "",
                "scanDetailsHtml": "",
                "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
                "isDelException": false,
                "isClearanceDelay": false,
                "isException": false,
                "isDelivered": false
            }],
            "originAddr1": "",
            "originAddr2": "",
            "originCity": "SEOUL",
            "originStateCD": "",
            "originZip": "",
            "originCntryCD": "KR",
            "originLocationID": "",
            "originTermCity": "SEOUL",
            "originTermStateCD": "",
            "destLocationAddr1": "",
            "destLocationAddr2": "",
            "destLocationCity": "LANTAU ISLAND",
            "destLocationStateCD": "",
            "destLocationZip": "",
            "destLocationCntryCD": "HK",
            "destLocationID": "",
            "destLocationTermCity": "LANTAU ISLAND",
            "destLocationTermStateCD": "",
            "destAddr1": "",
            "destAddr2": "",
            "destCity": "CHEK LAP KOK",
            "destStateCD": "",
            "destZip": "",
            "destCntryCD": "HK",
            "halAddr1": "",
            "halAddr2": "",
            "halCity": "",
            "halStateCD": "",
            "halZipCD": "",
            "halCntryCD": "",
            "actualDelAddrCity": "CHEK LAP KOK",
            "actualDelAddrStateCD": "",
            "actualDelAddrZipCD": "",
            "actualDelAddrCntryCD": "HK",
            "totalTransitMiles": "",
            "excepReasonList": [""],
            "excepActionList": [""],
            "exceptionReason": "",
            "exceptionAction": "",
            "statusDetailsList": [""],
            "trackErrCD": "",
            "destTZ": "\u002b08\u003a00",
            "originTZ": "\u002b09\u003a00",
            "isMultiStat": "0",
            "multiStatList": [{
                "multiPiec": "",
                "multiTm": "",
                "multiDispTm": "",
                "multiSta": ""
            }],
            "maskMessage": "",
            "deliveryService": "",
            "milestoDestination": "",
            "terms": "",
            "originUbanizationCode": "",
            "originCountryName": "",
            "isOriginResidential": false,
            "halUrbanizationCD": "",
            "halCountryName": "",
            "actualDelAddrUrbanizationCD": "",
            "actualDelAddrCountryName": "",
            "destUrbanizationCD": "",
            "destCountryName": "",
            "delToDesc": "Shipping\u002fReceiving",
            "recpShareID": "",
            "shprShareID": "9mbo6hrq0tqxo1i4pr7kp2yp",
            "defaultCDOType": "CDO",
            "mpstype": "",
            "fxfAdvanceNotice": true,
            "rthavailableCD": "",
            "excepReasonListNoInit": [""],
            "excepActionListNoInit": [""],
            "statusDetailsListNoInit": [""],
            "matched": false,
            "isSuccessful": true,
            "errorList": [{
                "code": "",
                "message": "",
                "source": null
            }],
            "isCanceled": false,
            "isPrePickup": false,
            "isPickup": false,
            "isInTransit": false,
            "isInProgress": true,
            "isDelException": false,
            "isClearanceDelay": false,
            "isException": false,
            "isDelivered": true,
            "isHAL": false,
            "isOnSchedule": false,
            "isDeliveryToday": false,
            "isSave": false,
            "isWatch": false,
            "isHistorical": false,
            "isTenderedNotification": false,
            "isDeliveredNotification": true,
            "isExceptionNotification": false,
            "isCurrentStatusNotification": false,
            "isAnticipatedShipDtLabel": false,
            "isShipPickupDtLabel": true,
            "isActualPickupLabel": false,
            "isOrderReceivedLabel": false,
            "isEstimatedDeliveryDtLabel": true,
            "isDeliveryDtLabel": false,
            "isActualDeliveryDtLabel": true,
            "isOrderCompleteLabel": false,
            "isOutboundDirection": false,
            "isInboundDirection": false,
            "isThirdpartyDirection": false,
            "isUnknownDirection": false,
            "isFSM": false,
            "isReturn": false,
            "isOriginalOutBound": false,
            "isChildPackage": false,
            "isParentPackage": false,
            "isReclassifiedAsSingleShipment": false,
            "isDuplicate": false,
            "isMaskShipper": false,
            "isHalEligible": false,
            "isFedexOfficeOnlineOrders": false,
            "isFedexOfficeInStoreOrders": false,
            "isMultipleStop": false,
            "isCustomCritical": false,
            "isInvalid": false,
            "isNotFound": false,
            "isFreight": false,
            "isSpod": true,
            "isSignatureAvailable": false,
            "isMPS": false,
            "isGMPS": false,
            "isResidential": false,
            "isDestResidential": true,
            "isHALResidential": false,
            "isActualDelAddrResidential": false,
            "isReqEstDelDt": false,
            "isCDOEligible": false,
            "CDOInfoList": [{
                "spclInstructDesc": "",
                "delivOptn": "",
                "delivOptnStatus": "",
                "reqApptWdw": "",
                "reqApptDesc": "",
                "rerouteTRKNbr": "",
                "beginTm": "",
                "endTm": ""
            }],
            "CDOExists": false,
            "isMtchdByRecShrID": false,
            "isMtchdByShiprShrID": false
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Just a follow up... I dont really know much about JSON objects, but it looks like its a complicated dictionary.  How would you go about parsing through and finding specific values within it?

Comment: @ImranHassanali: JSON is just a format, like XML. Once you parse it, it becomes a regular Python object.

Comment: How did you determine the structure and fields names for the data sent to FedEx? I want to do something similar, get tracking results by Reference number.

Comment: I think I found the answer. I loaded HTTP Trace extension http://goo.gl/qDyIqL in Chrome browser, started recording on a blank FedEx tracking page, populated the fields manually and pressed the Track button. The POST appeared in the trace. Now I can automate the same. Your example was helpful.

Comment: Just to add a note, you can send up to 30 tracking numbers per request. i find it takes about 1 second for each request.

Comment: Anybody have a reference to UPS and USPS's similar method for obtaining this information?  I assume they all use JavaScript similarly to this FedEx example.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I ended up with, thanks to @Blender

```
import requests
import json

daysdict = {1:31,2:28,3:31,4:31,5:31,6:30,7:31,8:31,9:30,10:31,11:30,12:31}
def days_in_month(month):
    for key, value in daysdict.iteritems():
        if key == month:
            number_of_days = value
    return number_of_days




def build_output(tracking_number):

    data = requests.post('https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track', data={
        'data': json.dumps({
            'TrackPackagesRequest': {
                'appType': 'wtrk',
                'uniqueKey': '',
                'processingParameters': {
                    'anonymousTransaction': True,
                    'clientId': 'WTRK',
                    'returnDetailedErrors': True,
                    'returnLocalizedDateTime': False
                },
                'trackingInfoList': [{
                    'trackNumberInfo': {
                        'trackingNumber': tracking_number,
                        'trackingQualifier': '',
                        'trackingCarrier': ''
                    }
                }]
            }
        }),
        'action': 'trackpackages',
        'locale': 'en_US',
        'format': 'json',
        'version': 99
    }).json()

    return data

# finds delivery date info

ship_arrival_key = 'displayActDeliveryDateTime'
ship_time_key = 'displayShipDt'



def track(tracking_number):

    data = build_output(tracking_number)
     #narrowing down dictionary and lists to objects needed (ship day,arrival)
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        narrow = value 
    #narrow more into packageList list
    for key, value in narrow.iteritems():
        if key == 'packageList':
            narrow = value
    # narrow to ship start value
    for x, y in narrow[0].iteritems():
        if x == ship_arrival_key:
            ship_arival_value = y
            exists = True

    # also find ship arrival
        elif x == ship_time_key:
            ship_time_value = y
            exists = True
    # list with two items shiptime and shiparrival

    return  ship_time_value, ship_arival_value, exists


def print_results(tracking_number):
    to_fro = track(tracking_number)
    if to_fro[2] == True:
        try:
            daysinmonth = days_in_month(int(to_fro[0][0]))
            try:
                if to_fro[0][0] != to_fro[1][0]:

                    ship_days = str(    (int(daysinmonth) - int(str((to_fro[0][2]))+str((to_fro[0][3])))  + int(to_fro[1][3])) )

                    print '_____________________'
                    print 'Shipped: ' + to_fro[0]
                    print 'Arrived: ' + to_fro[1]
                    print '_____________________'
                    print '\nShipping took:' +"     "  +ship_days  
                else:
                    ship_days = int(to_fro[1][2] + to_fro[1][3]) - int(to_fro[0][2] + to_fro[0][3])
                    print '_____________________'
                    print 'Shipped: ' + to_fro[0]
                    print 'Arrived: ' + to_fro[1]
                    print '_____________________'
                    print  '\nShipping took:' +"    " +  str(ship_days)  
            except IndexError:
                print 'Invalid Tracking Number'
                pass
        except IndexError:
            pass
    else:
        pass

def raw_results(tracking_number):
    to_fro = track(tracking_number)
    if to_fro[2] == True:
        daysinmonth = days_in_month(int(track(tracking_number)[0][0]))
        try:
            if to_fro[0][0] != to_fro[1][0]:

                ship_days = str(    (int(daysinmonth) - int(str((to_fro[0][2]))+str((to_fro[0][3])))  + int(to_fro[1][3])) )
            else:
                ship_days = int(to_fro[1][2] + to_fro[1][3]) - int(to_fro[0][2] + to_fro[0][3])
        except IndexError:
            print 'Invalid Tracking Number'
            pass
    else:
        pass

    return ship_days



#print_results(499552080632881)
```