# Need help scraping tracking number details from UPS website with Python without API

Tags: python, web-scraping, ups

I want to build a simple python program that gets updates for tracking numbers from UPS, I couldn't get an account number with them so I can't use their API. I decided to try web scraping.

Here's an example of a tracking number:
https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=1Z0X118AYW08592000&requester=WT/trackdetails

I want to get the scheduled delivery date, the problem is that what the requests module scrapes and what shows when I view the page source doesn't get all the information inside a tag called app-root. That's where the delivery date is.

I found a similar post that solves this problem with FedEx, but I can't get it to work with the ups website: [Parsing HTML does not output desired data(tracking info for FedEx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817185/parsing-html-does-not-output-desired-datatracking-info-for-fedex)

I installed an extension called HTTP Trace that shows all the requests that go through my server, I can't find the one that matches UPS, this is what I got from the extension when I searched for the tracking number, any ideas what I can do here?

```
https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_IL
HTMLVersion: 5.0
loc: en_IL
track.x: Track
trackNums: 1Z0X118AYW08592000
ups-search: 1Z0X118AYW08592000

POST https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_IL
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
 Redirect to: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_IL&tracknum=1Z0X118AYW08592000&requester=WT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_IL&tracknum=1Z0X118AYW08592000&requester=WT
Content-Length: 365
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 00:32:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
Server-Timing: edge; dur=164
Server-Timing: origin; dur=23
Debug-AK-TLS: No bypass

GET https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_IL&tracknum=1Z0X118AYW08592000&requester=WT
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Debug-AK-TLS: No bypass
X-Akamai-Transformed: 9 9152 0 pmb=mTOE,1mRUM,1
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 00:32:34 GMT
Content-Length: 10947
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
Server-Timing: edge; dur=182
Server-Timing: origin; dur=201

https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=969628123173894&ev=PageView&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2Ftrack%3Floc%3Den_IL%26tracknum%3D1Z0X118AYW08592000%26requester%3DWT%2Ftrackdetails&rl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2F&if=false&ts=1610584355509&sw=1920&sh=1080&v=2.9.32&r=stable&a=tmtealium&ec=0&o=30&fbp=fb.1.1598067407332.38393503&it=1610584355413&coo=false&dpo=LDU&dpoco=0&dpost=0&rqm=GET

GET https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=969628123173894&ev=PageView&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2Ftrack%3Floc%3Den_IL%26tracknum%3D1Z0X118AYW08592000%26requester%3DWT%2Ftrackdetails&rl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2F&if=false&ts=1610584355509&sw=1920&sh=1080&v=2.9.32&r=stable&a=tmtealium&ec=0&o=30&fbp=fb.1.1598067407332.38393503&it=1610584355413&coo=false&dpo=LDU&dpoco=0&dpost=0&rqm=GET
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 302
 Redirect to: https://cx.atdmt.com/?c=1479770850078954307&f=AYzL_IHfyiIJ9HIa7oqq8XcmRPtLo6M0aKkForULuTS_d5qgkpmUtO1x4Rmi3jkdZ4EPRHG7qxKZDTiWb-BA5MYf&id=969628123173894&l=3&v=0
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 00:32:36 GMT
location: https://cx.atdmt.com/?c=1479770850078954307&f=AYzL_IHfyiIJ9HIa7oqq8XcmRPtLo6M0aKkForULuTS_d5qgkpmUtO1x4Rmi3jkdZ4EPRHG7qxKZDTiWb-BA5MYf&id=969628123173894&l=3&v=0
content-type: text/plain
content-length: 0
server: proxygen-bolt
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600

GET https://cx.atdmt.com/?c=1479770850078954307&f=AYzL_IHfyiIJ9HIa7oqq8XcmRPtLo6M0aKkForULuTS_d5qgkpmUtO1x4Rmi3jkdZ4EPRHG7qxKZDTiWb-BA5MYf&id=969628123173894&l=3&v=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200
x-fb-rlafr: 0
content-type: image/gif
date: Wed, 13 Jan 2021 16:32:37 PST
x-content-type-options: nosniff
report-to: {"group":"coep_report","max_age":86400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/browser_reporting\/"}]}
cache-control: public, max-age=0
content-encoding: br
x-frame-options: DENY
cross-origin-resource-policy: cross-origin
expires: Wed, 13 Jan 2021 16:32:37 PST
vary: Accept-Encoding
cross-origin-embedder-policy-report-only: require-corp;report-to="coep_report"
pragma: public
x-fb-debug: ySiesinmQSMWtIWGg5+rMp+g66R70GGiqJJC3M0DowZMGuFf14OidRiX02DfG99gXxjUSjCaEtHosxh/9tl/hQ==
```

Comment: What prevents you getting an account and using the UPS Tracking API?

Comment: did you try adding cookies and x-headers from browser to your request

Comment: - UPS requires a payment account for the API, and it wouldn't let me open one.

- How do I add cookies and x-headers to the request? I'm not sure which request I should use, I tried some of the get requests and got back 200, but I don't know where to get the data from.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly do not believe this is possible. I checked how UPS loads its sites, and it seems to load the frontend first like this

[Get request to website preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giXQv.png)

then goes in to the api to grab the dates. For example, the delivered on date is stored in this api link ("https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US") which needs a bunch of headers and has some akamai/security cookies (which may prevent you from scraping it).

If you really do not want to use an api, I would suggest using something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) if you do not need it to be quick/do not have many links to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice is either Selenium OR API but that comes with a hitch. For what I can tell on the UPS website, their API only allows for queries at night. They only want "emergencies" to be hitting their API, which is preposterous since I would imagine web requests are hitting the same API.